# How to delete a row in a big mysql table and busy server?

Tags: mysql, server, delete-row

When I DELETE a row into a table with several million lines and a server with lots of traffic, it produces excessive load and cut the traffic for more than 30 seconds.
Another way to do?

Comment: This question should better be asked on : http://dba.stackexchange.com/, I think you'll get a proper answer there.

Comment: show your table structure and the delete statement how you are deleting row...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use the primary key to reference the row to delete. 
Use EXPLAIN on the delete query to get information about what MySQL is doing to resolve the query, specifically check it has chosen a good index in the 'key' column and a low number of rows in the 'rows' column.

If unsure, then paste the output of EXPLAIN along with the information Zafar requested and you'll get more help.